# How to customize checkout flow with PayPal's checkout.js when creating the payment on the backend?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using PayPal's checkout.js with server side integration, as described here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/

Everything works. Except that it shows shipping address that I'd like to disable, as I'm selling digital goods.

When clicking on the button, PayPal posts a request to the server to create the payment.

On the server, I'm creating a subscription plan, activating it, creating an associated billing agreement and passing the agreement's token back to the client.

Unlike the client-side integration, I don't call button.create() function and there's no way to pass experience options.

I've tried  to create an experience web profile using the experience api, but apparently this is not supported for plans:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/4